# Showing a given holomorphic function $f$ satisfies $|f''(0)| \leq 2$ and $|f(z)|\leq|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function from $D$ to $D$, where $D$ is the open unit disk. Suppose that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$. Show that$|f''(0)| \leq 2$ and $|f(z)|<|z|^2$ for all $z \in D$.

Thoughts so far: I think this must be an application of the Schwarz Lemma, but I can't get it to work out. Since $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$ we have that $f(z) = z^2g$ for some holomorphic $g$. Now, if I can show that $f'(D) \subset D$ then I can prove part one by Cauchy Estimates, but I don't see why this is true. The second part follows if I can show that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ on $D$ for some reason, though I don't see why this is true. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Should the second inequality be $|f(z)| \leq |z|^2$? If the inequality were strict, this contradicts the assumption that $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: All you need to prove is $|g(z)|\le 1$ in $D$, and the proof goes almost verbatim as for [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Proof). Minor variation that you divide by $z^2$ (and $f''(0)=2g(0)$), but it does not affect the idea. Then both parts follows easily from that inequality.

Comment: @A.G. Does the fact that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ in $D$ really follow so easily? I see from the Schwarz Lemma that $|z^2g(z)| \leq |z|$ (since $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ by Schwarz), but I don't see how this gets us where we want to go.

Comment: @m.deslauriers Cancelling $|z|$ gives for $F(z)=zg(z)$ that $|F|\le 1$ and $F(0)=0$. Now apply Schwarz again.

Comment: @A.G. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $f:D \to D$ is holomorphic and $f(D) \subset D,$ then $|f''(0)| \le 2$ by Cauchy's estimates. We don't need $f(0)= f'(0)=0$ for this. We do need $f(0)= f'(0)=0$ for the estimate $|f(z)|\le |z|^2,$ but this is independent of first part; it follows from the proof idea in the Schwarz Lemma as @A.G. suggested in a comment.